King and Rook vs King (Passing Allowed)
It is well known that King and Rook always defeat a lone King. However, this requires the use of zugzwang. If passing were allowed then experimentation suggests the weaker side should always draw, unless the starting position was extremely unfavourable.
Let us suggest a modified rule: passing is legal only if the opponent did not pass on his previous turn. This means e.g. that White could choose to pass indefinitely until Black puts him in check.
White to play and win
White: Kd6 Rc1, Black: Kc8 Rc7


Can you please explain what passing means?

@Will.Octagon.Gibson Pass your turn, making no move.

So there is no stalemate right? Also can I post partial answers?

Right. As @Lucenaposition asked, would "stalemate when passed to you" = loss?

@Lucenaposition stalemate can occur with e.g. 1 Rxc7+ Kb8 2 Kc6 pass 3 Rb7+ Ka8 4 pass. Stalemate counts as a draw.

I believe the following covers all essential lines of play.

 1.Rxc7+ Kd8 (Kb8? 2.Kc6 pass 3.Re7 pass 3.Re8+ Ka7 4.pass Ka6 5.Ra8#) 2.Re7 pass (Kc8 3.Rd7) 3.Re5 pass (Kc8 4.Kc6 Kd8 5.pass Kc8 6.Re8#) 4.Rf5 Kc8 (Ke8 5.pass Kd8 6.Rf8#) 5.Rf7 pass 6.Rd7 pass 7.Kc6 pass 8.Rd5 pass 9.Re5 Kb8 (Kd8 10 pass Kc8 11.Re8#) 10.Re8+ Ka7 11.pass Ka6 12.Ra8#

A key element is to recreate black's (standard rules) zugzwang by passing with white (after threatening mate, so black cannot prevent white from passing by passing themselves).

I had a slightly different solution, giving Black a choice of dying in the a8 or h8 corner. Albert's solution is "superior" in that it generalises to a board of arbitrary size. Even if Black's king is not confined to the edge of the board, White can "do the procedure" (apologies to Kramnik!) repeatedly, one row at a time :)

Idea: to make an animation for people who don't have a chess board, give dummy pieces like one Knight for each side in unrelated corners of the board -- this way you can attach a link to a free analysis board like Lichess.
